# Can I delete this Kaspersky Temp File safely?

Tags: anti-virus, kaspersky, temporary-files

Kaspersky files are taking a lot of space and so I went online and found out how to delete Kaspersky temp files. However I couldn't find any files ending in .tmp (yes, I have show hidden folders on) and I found this file called temp with a file called kasdb.fs.tmpa05224. I was wondering whether I could delete this Kaspersky file as I'm running out of space. Thanks!

Comment: Which Kaspersky product and version is it? Where that file you want to remove is located?

Comment: Kaspersky Anti-Virus 2011.

Answer (score 0):

The files `kasdb.fs.tmp*` appear in the update Kaspersky Anti-Virus. If you need to remove them to stop antivirus. Delete the files. Run the antivirus again. It only makes sense in case of problems with the service update Kaspersky Anti-Virus.